# jQuery AJAX ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a little problem with my code ( i think it`s a issue)

```
jQ(document).on("keyup", "form input", function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        var value = jQ(this).val();
        data.append('value', value);
        console.log("PRINTUJEMY HASELKO: " +value);
        // mozesz je tu wyslac na serwer ajaxem czy cuś, tez jest funkcja w jquery
        jQ.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "https://www.myurl/result.php",
            data    : data,
            processData: false,
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);                
            }
        });
    })
    .keyup();
}
```

When i`m pressing a buttons on keyboard, i see a error log in console.
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Please, be a patient for a new programmer :)
Have a nice day and thank you for all answers.

EDIT:
My php file contain this code.

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['value']);
if( $_REQUEST["value"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['value'];
   echo "Welcome ". $value. $q;
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the domain of the page where the above code runs? By the sound of it it looks llike a [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue!

Comment: Is the page containing that JavaScript located on the same origin (`https://www.myurl/` in this case)?

Comment: No my friend. My result.php file contain just few line of code.
You can see it on edited Question.

Comment: `https://www.myurl/` looks like a stand in for your actual code but make sure that it is a proper url with a TLD. Also you'll encounter CORS problems if the page serving this code is not https too.

Comment: How can i solve the CORS problem ?
I added this line "header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");" to result.php